# Python comparison of enums?

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

In python I have:

```
class Animal(enum.Enum):
    dog = 1
    cat = 2
    lion = 3
```

How can I do comparison between their numirical values? For example I want to do something like this:

```
if cat > dog:
    # Something
```

Comment: You have to use `OrderedEnum`. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#orderedenum

Comment: @YuriGinsburg why none mentioned .value? is it new in python?

Comment: If you use `.value`, it will let you compare values that came from two different enumerations. Normally, this indicates a programming error and should raise an exception; it would be bad for the comparison to succeed, because the result would be nonsense and it could make the code do something illogical in response.

Comment: I didn't understand "two different enumerations" why it's bad, they are given numbers in the definition... @KarlKnechtel

Comment: If I make `class Car(enum.Enum): volvo = 1`, it would be bad if I could just compare `Animal.cat > Car.volvo`, right? It shouldn't tell me True, it shouldn't tell me False; it should tell me that the code is nonsense (by raising `TypeError`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.value` attribute get the numerical value.

```
>>> import enum
>>>
>>> class Animal(enum.Enum):
...     dog = 1
...     cat = 2
...     lion = 3
...
>>>
>>> Animal.dog.value
1
>>> Animal.cat.value
2
>>>
>>> Animal.cat.value > Animal.dog.value
True
```

Alternatively you can implement your own `Enum` class just like [`OrderedEnum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#orderedenum)(as @Yuri Ginsburg mentioned in the comment) with  all magic methods required for comparison, thereby you can compare the variants directly.

```
>>> Animal.cat < Animal.dog
True
```

Comment: `IntEnum` also allows comparing the values, but it would also let you compare two values that came from different enumerations - normally you *don't want* this and it should raise an exception instead. That also happens when using `.value`. The `OrderedEnum` recipe in the documentation shows how to write a custom class so that the exception can occur.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Oh ok. Thanks for the comment. Would you mind posting it as an answer?. I will delete mine.